# Some OneToMany relationships are returned as objects and some as IRIs - API-Platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I would like to include related questions and question groups as list of IRIs when I make get request to Form.

I have few entities:

- Form (fields: question_groups, questions)
- QuestionGroup (fields: form, questions)
- Question (fields: form, question_group)

When I make get request for the form, it returns:

- Form

  - questions ['/api/questions/1',...]
  - questionGroups [{id:1,name:'foo',questions: ['/api/questions/1',...]...},...]

As you can see, Form.questions is list of IRIs but Form.questionGroups is list of objects. I would like to have both of them as IRIs.

On the image below under questionGroups field there is a questionGroup field but there is no question field under questions or answer under answers,...

[image]

The whole thing makes no sense to me, I have tried to set @MaxDepth, it changed nothing (except when i have used @MaxDepth(0) which threw 500 error without any error massage in response or in php log)

Can anyone explain why, and what should I do to load both questions and questionGroups as list of IRIs?

Thank you

Here are relevant parts of entities mentioned above.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deleted_at", timeAware=false, hardDelete=true)
 */
class Form
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=200, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="QuestionGroup", mappedBy="form", cascade={"REMOVE"})
     */
    private $question_groups;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Question", mappedBy="form", cascade={"REMOVE"})
     */
    private $questions;


}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deleted_at", timeAware=false, hardDelete=true)
 */
class QuestionGroup
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Form",inversedBy="question_groups")
     */
    private $form;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Question", mappedBy="question_group", cascade={"REMOVE"})
     */
    private $questions;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deleted_at", timeAware=false, hardDelete=true)
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Form",inversedBy="questions")
     */
    private $form;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="QuestionGroup", inversedBy="questions")
     */
    private $question_group;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that if Entity field/property is snake_case like "$question_groups" then API will return it as list of objects and if its camelCase like "$questionGroups" it will be returned as list of IRIs. Side note: normalisationContext does not like snake_case. if you use normalisationContext and the property is snake_cased than it will be not included in the response data.